# Override libc functions without LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, dynamic-linking

I'm planning to implement my own malloc/free and I ran into some problems while trying to link my shared library with my executable.

Right now, I can get it to work with LD_PRELOAD, but not by linking the .so to the executable, although I can get similiar libraries, like tcmalloc, to work properly just by linking them to my executable, and would like to do the same.

I'm building everything with cmake, this is the CMakeLists of my shared library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(allocator)

add_library(allocator SHARED exports.cpp)
target_link_libraries(allocator dl)

target_compile_features(allocator PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
```

and this is exports.cpp:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void * (*MallocType)(size_t);
typedef void (*FreeType)(void *);

static bool g_initialized = false;

static MallocType real_malloc = nullptr;
static FreeType   real_free   = nullptr;

static void alloc_init(void)
{
    real_malloc = (MallocType) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

    if (!real_malloc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in `dlsym`: %s\n", dlerror());
    }

    real_free = (FreeType) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "free");

    if (!real_free)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in `dlsym`: %s\n", dlerror());
    }

    g_initialized = true;
}

extern "C" void * malloc(size_t size)
{
    if (!g_initialized)
    {
        alloc_init();
    }

    printf("Allocate %u.\n", size);
    return real_malloc(size);
}

extern "C" void free(void *ptr)
{
    if (!g_initialized)
    {
        alloc_init();
    }

    printf("Free %p.\n", ptr);
    real_free(ptr);
}
```

As I said, trying to link the resulting .so to an executable doesn't really link the library (there's no entry in ldd, and libc malloc is called). I was wondering what am I doing wrong.

Edit:
I've also tried compiling with

```
g++ -o liballocator.so -shared exports.cpp -std=c++11 -fPIC -ldl
g++ -o test launcher.cpp memusage.cpp app.cpp -ldl -L. -lallocator -std=c++11
```

Comment: That's apparently not C, but compiled with a C++ compiler. Compile C as C and link with your C++ code using a correcponding header. The names of the standard library are reserved. Using them (the way you do here at least) invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: It might be illuminating to enable detailed output from make, and to examine the link commands actually executed.

Comment: I tried compiling plain C but the result was the same, also I would assume I should be able to link C++ code as well, especially because LD_PRELOAD actually works.

Comment: Can't repro on Ubuntu 14.04, the library is linked just fine and successfully interposes Glibc allocator at runtime...

Comment: I don't know why, but it works now, I didn't change anything since yesterday, whatever.

Comment: Did you know that when you write C++, the compiler supports replacing `new/delete` **without** library tricks?

Comment: @MSalters: wouldn't you need to rebuild your code for this? The whole purpose of LD_PRELOAD is interposing symbols without rebuild.

Comment: @tuccio: as a side note, be sure to add other parts of allocator to your library (calloc, realloc, memalign, etc.) or you'll suffer pretty bad bugs at runtime. Also your lazy initialization is subject to race conditions in multithreaded program.

Comment: @yugr: Yes, a rebuild is needed. Doesn't seem to be a problem here.

Comment: @yugr Thank you, I'm aware, as you might guess the code I pasted was just a rough example of what I'm trying to achieve, to display the problem with simple code.

Answer (score 2):

CMake isn't your tool of choice here. CMake creates makefiles or IDE project files for C source, and has a kind of working assumption that all the code is doing conventional things in conventional ways. That is no longer true if you have undertaken to provide your own malloc.

Most C compilers can be coaxed into linking a user-supplied version of malloc, often by playing about with the order of the link flags. But it is an error-prone process, since  there might be indirect calls or submodules bound early. You can instantly solve all those problems by renaming malloc() mymalloc(), but then of course you must rewrite the client code.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Same goes for C++: it isn't part of the solution, it is part of the problem.